# Why does the "command" directly open and not when clicked on Button? Python 3

Tags: button, tkinter, command

I pretty new in this whole Python thing and my question is how to make, that a button runs the command, when clicking it and not before.
I searched much in the Internet but i didnt find anything. 
I dont understand the classes at all. Is there no other way to do this?

Here is my work, i did on the programm.
Thanks for your help

```
from tkinter import *
import os
t = ""

def ordner(x):
    print ("def")
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join("/Kunden/",x)) == True:
        pass
    else:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join("/Kunden/",x))

def E1holen():
    x = E1.get()
    ordner(x)


#Hauptfenster
main=Tk(className='Kundendatenbank')
main.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
#Inhalt Hauptfenster
L1 = Label(main, text="Kundenname:")
L1.pack(side = LEFT)
E1 = Entry(main, bd =5, textvariable=t)
E1.pack(side = RIGHT)
a = Button (main, text=("erstellen/bearbeiten"), command=E1holen()).pack()

main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It runs immediately ecause you tell it to.

What is the syntax for calling a function in Python? It's `foo()`, right? So, when you do `command=E1holen()`, what should python do? It should call `E1holen()`, and then pass the result to the `command` attribute.

Put another way, the `command` attribute takes a *reference* to a function, but because of the `()` you were *calling* the function and giving the `command` attribute whatever that function returned. The solution? Remove the `()`:

```
a = Button(..., command=E1holen)
```